# Push notification not working on android codenameone

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I followed this tutorial https://www.codenameone.com/manual/push.html
and registered my application with Display.getInstance().registerPush();

I am doing tests with a rest post

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://push.codenameone.com/push/push?token=34C35DCB-XXX-4A56-XXXX-XXXXXX&device=cn1-fcm-e9Xvk0mdGdc:APAXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-7-z3Ax7HNkeEvcvCl3_1zQdBbxurWcUSMenXFJgM2w0UTRE0ziUz_N7TIzxOOblktGSPsEmCH7q09pJQJ1v0mQZO7LNvyP4UEOlsdRds&auth=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&type=3&body=test'
```

I am getting this answer:

```
[
    {
        "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "status": "OK"
    }
]
```

But nothing on the phone. I have to mention that the app was installed as APK not from the play store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type 3 is a mix of hidden and visible types. Try type 1 which is 100% visible push notification or if you use type 3 use a semicolon to separate the hidden payload and the visible portion in your data.

See [this](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/push.html#_push_types_and_message_structure) under "Push Types and Message Structure".

Comment: Thanks indeed it worked i just didn't notice because when the app is opened and foreground the notification doesn't show. Thanks a lot !